# AppAuth semantic and parse issues are breaking build of react native project in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I am using create-react-native-app to build an ios app. I have detached to expokit in order to use the payment API. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html
I then follow this guide: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html

My problem starts when I want to build my project with Xcode, I get these errors [My errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b4jL.png)

1) Unknown type name 'SFAuthenticationSession'
2) Use of undeclared identifier 'SFAuthenticationSession'
3) Use of undeclared identifier 'authenticationVC'
4) Unrecognized platform name iOS

I'm not sure what they mean and how to fix them

Comment: Please post your errors as text so that they are searchable. So if others have the same error they can find your question, and hopefully an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build with expokit you always need to have the latest version of Xcode. These problems were caused by me not having Xcode 9